# Problem while reading SQL query in python. "\x00" added after each character

Tags: python

I am trying to read a query within python but reading the query generates a weird string.

It adds the following characters `ÿþ/`at the beginning of the imported query and then it includes what looks like a space after each single character.

Running `str(qry)` shows that the spaces are actually the following characters: `\x00`.

Below is my script:

```
server='myserver'
database = "mydb"
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')

mysqlquery=open('\mysqlquery.SQL','r')
qry=mysqlquery.read()
mysqlquery.close()

df=pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_sql(qry,conn,chunksize=10**5):
    df=pd.concat([df,chunk])
```

Comment: Try opening your query with different encoding like utf-16 etc `open('\mysqlquery.SQL','r', encoding='utf-16')`

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks =). Feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file seems to be `utf-16`-encoded as each ascii character is padded to 2 bytes with `\x00`. The default encoding for `open` is platform dependent (use `locale.getpreferredencoding()` to check yours). To override it use the `encoding` argument:

```py
open('\mysqlquery.SQL','r', encoding='utf-16')
```